# SQL: Check if value is available in tbl1 or tbl2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a sub-account system (PHP & MYSQL).

I have a user table (users) and a sub users table (sub_users).

**How can check if the user is available in the user table, or in the sub users table?**

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM users
 WHERE userid = "steven"
    OR WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                       FROM sub_users
                      WHERE sub_users.userid = "steven");
```

ERROR: Check your syntax near "steven"

Also tried:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
  LEFT JOIN sub_users
    ON sub_users.user_userid = users.userid
 WHERE users.userid = 'steven' 
    OR sub_users.userid = 'steven'
```

Same error.

Comment: Are you sure second query returns the same error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first place, you only want one `where` clause.  I would also use single quote instead of double quotes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM users
WHERE userid = 'steven' or
      EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM sub_users
              WHERE sub_users.userid = 'steven'
             );
```

I doubt you need the `distinct` keyword, if you are fetching all the columns from `users`.

Your second query looks ok.  Are you sure you are not running the first query twice?

EDIT:

I'm trying to figure out what you want to return.  The following returns 1 if `'steven'` appears in either table and 0 otherwise:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from users where users.userid = 'steven') and
                  exists (select 1 from sub_users where sub_users.userid = 'steven')
             then 1
             else 0
        end);
```

This method saves on the overhead of a `join` and will readily take advantage of indexes on `users(userid)` and `sub_users(userid)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(select * from users) x,
(select * from sub_users) y
where x.user_id = 'steven' or y.user_id = 'steven'
```

Good luck !!!

Comment: Thank you Eitan. Works fine too!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a union:

```
(SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = 'steven')
UNION
(SELECT userid FROM sub_users WHERE userid = 'steven');
```

Comment: Thank you Brad, Works fine too!